# Profile likelihood confidence intervals = (-Inf Inf) in a glmer {lme4_1.1-7}

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, profile-likelihood

I fitted a mixed logit model with crossed random effects in `lme4_1.1-7::glmer` (R version 3.1.1 / OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks).

Had to simplify the maximal random-effect structure justified by the design due to failed convergence; the final model is estimated without any problems:

```
fitted_1 <- glmer(DV ~ IV1.d*IV2.d + (IV1.d*IV2.d| SubjN) + (1|Items) +  
                       (0+IV1.d|Items) + (0+IV2.d|Items) + (0+IV1.d:IV2.d|Items), 
                  glmerControl(optimizer='bobyqa', optCtrl = list(maxfun=20000)), 
                  data=myPP, family=binomial)
```

`DV` is the binary response variable

`IV1.d` and `IV2.d` are two within-subjects within-items categorical predictors, two levels each, deviation-contrast coded (values: -.5/.5)

I tried to compute confidence intervals for the beta parameters using profile likelihood via `confint.merMod()` but the computation seems to be failing.
For all betas, I got values `(-Inf Inf)` and warning messages of non-monotonic profiles. Reading on [R-sig-ME], this latter issue should mean there is something wonky with the profile.

I tried to simplify the random structure of the model until profile confidence intervals could be computed. Here is the model:

```
fitted_4 <- glmer(DV ~ IV1.d + IV2.d + IV1.d:IV2.d + (IV1.d + IV2.d| SubjN) +
                       (1|Items) + (0+IV1.d|Items) + (0 +IV2.d|Items), data=myPP, 
                  glmerControl(optimizer='bobyqa', optCtrl = list(maxfun=20000)),
                  family=binomial)
```

1. I'm not understanding what causes the profile likelihood method to fail for the original `fitted_1` model but not for `fitted_4`.
2. Is there any other way I could obtain profile CI's for `fitted_1`?

---

```
summary(fitted_1)

##       AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
##    1074.0   1168.1   -519.0   1038.0     1362 

##  Scaled residuals: 
##      Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
##  -2.2673 -0.3611 -0.2500 -0.1378  4.5826 

##  Random effects:
##   Groups  Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr             
##   SubjN   (Intercept) 2.424e+00 1.557e+00                  
##           IV1.d       1.990e+00 1.411e+00  0.17            
##           IV2.d       6.065e-01 7.788e-01 -0.97 -0.29      
##           IV1.d:IV2.d 2.172e+00 1.474e+00 -0.19 -0.81  0.39
##   Items   (Intercept) 4.615e-03 6.793e-02                  
##   Items.1 IV1.d       3.233e-13 5.686e-07                  
##   Items.2 IV2.d       9.442e-01 9.717e-01                  
##   Items.3 IV1.d:IV2.d 4.801e-01 6.929e-01                  
##  Number of obs: 1380, groups:  SubjN, 88; Items, 12

##  Fixed effects:
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
##  (Intercept) -2.40604    0.23196 -10.373   <2e-16 ***
##  IV1.d        0.08249    0.36355   0.227   0.8205    
##  IV2.d        1.11046    0.43579   2.548   0.0108 *  
##  IV1.d:IV2.d  0.16386    0.71246   0.230   0.8181    

##  Correlation of Fixed Effects:
##              (Intr) IV1.d  IV2.d 
##  IV1.d        0.118              
##  IV2.d       -0.434 -0.083       
##  IV1.d:IV2.d -0.090 -0.628  0.064
```

```
confint(fitted_1, method="profile", which='beta_')`

##               2.5 % 97.5 %
##   (Intercept)  -Inf    Inf
##   IV1.d        -Inf    Inf
##   IV2.d        -Inf    Inf
##   IV1.d:IV2.d  -Inf    Inf

##  Warning messages:
##  1: In profile.merMod(object, signames = oldNames, ...) :
##    non-monotonic profile
##  2: In profile.merMod(object, signames = oldNames, ...) :
##    non-monotonic profile
##  3: In profile.merMod(object, signames = oldNames, ...) :
##    non-monotonic profile
##  4: In profile.merMod(object, signames = oldNames, ...) :
##    non-monotonic profile
```

```
summary(fitted_4)

##       AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
##      1068     1136     -521     1042     1367 

##  Scaled residuals: 
##      Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
##  -2.3575 -0.3555 -0.2522 -0.1613  4.6391 

##  Random effects:
##   Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
##   SubjN   (Intercept) 2.23144  1.4938              
##           IV1.d       1.53606  1.2394    0.09      
##           IV2.d       0.31120  0.5579   -1.00 -0.18
##   Items   (Intercept) 0.01344  0.1159              
##   Items.1 IV1.d       0.00000  0.0000              
##   Items.2 IV2.d       0.92942  0.9641              
##  Number of obs: 1380, groups:  SubjN, 88; Items, 12

##  Fixed effects:
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
##  (Intercept) -2.30252    0.21029 -10.949   <2e-16 ***
##  IV1.d        0.17448    0.27729   0.629   0.5292    
##  IV2.d        0.80072    0.36862   2.172   0.0298 *  
##  IV1.d:IV2.d  0.01351    0.41660   0.032   0.9741    

##  Correlation of Fixed Effects:
##              (Intr) IV1.d  IV2.d 
##  IV1.d        0.012              
##  IV2.d       -0.274 -0.010       
##  IV1.d:IV2.d  0.006 -0.255 -0.038
```

```
confint(fitted_4, which='beta_', method='profile')

##                    2.5 %     97.5 %
##  (Intercept) -2.74571641 -1.9052351
##  IV1.d       -0.37989551  0.7320931
##  IV2.d        0.03993436  1.5903197
##  IV1.d:IV2.d -0.80790153  0.8346440
```

---

### UPDATE

```
## re-compute profiles for both random and fixed effects

pp <- profile(fitted_1)

## 24 warnings with profile(fitted_1) of the types:
## In profile.merMod(fitted_1) : non-monotonic profile
## In optwrap(optimizer, par = start, fn = function(x) dd(mkpar(npar1,  ... :
   # convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function evaluations exceeded

(c_ci <- confint(pp))

## 2.5 % 97.5 %
## .sig01          0    Inf
## .sig02         -1      1
## .sig03         -1      1
## .sig04         -1      1
## .sig05          0    Inf
## .sig06         -1      1
## .sig07         -1      1
## .sig08          0    Inf
## .sig09         -1      1
## .sig10          0    Inf
## .sig11          0    Inf
## .sig12          0    Inf
## .sig13          0    Inf
## .sig14          0    Inf
## (Intercept)  -Inf    Inf
## IV1.d        -Inf    Inf
## IV2.d        -Inf    Inf
## IV1.d:IV2.d  -Inf    Inf


## plot the profiles (all weird)
    ggplot(as.data.frame(pp),aes(.focal,.zeta))+
    geom_point()+geom_line()+
    facet_wrap(~.par,scale="free_x")+
    geom_hline(yintercept=0,colour="gray")+
    geom_hline(yintercept=c(-1.96,1.96),linetype=2,
               colour="gray")
```

[image: Plot_profile_fitted1.jpeg]

```
### setting delta to a smaller value to make the profile stepsize smaller
system.time(pp2 <- profile(fitted_1, delta = 0.1))

## user    system   elapsed 
## 64292.282   135.451 75676.403

## Warning messages:
## 1: In profile.merMod(orig.pp, delta = 0.1) : non-monotonic profile
## 2: display list redraw incomplete
## [...]

c_ci2 <- confint(pp2)
c_ci2

## 2.5 % 97.5 %
## .sig01          0    Inf
## .sig02         -1      1
## .sig03         -1      1
## .sig04         -1      1
## .sig05          0    Inf
## .sig06         -1      1
## .sig07         -1      1
## .sig08          0    Inf
## .sig09         -1      1
## .sig10          0    Inf
## .sig11          0    Inf
## .sig12          0    Inf
## .sig13          0    Inf
## .sig14          0    Inf
## (Intercept)  -Inf    Inf
## IV1.d        -Inf    Inf
## IV2.d        -Inf    Inf
## IV1.d:IV2.d  -Inf    Inf


## plot of profiles (delta = 0.1)

ggplot(as.data.frame(pp2),aes(.focal,.zeta))+
    geom_point()+geom_line()+
    facet_wrap(~.par,scale="free_x")+
    geom_hline(yintercept=0,colour="gray")+
    geom_hline(yintercept=c(-1.96,1.96),linetype=2,
               colour="gray")
```

[image: Plot of profiles delta = 0.1]

Comment: (1) in what precise way is the computation failing (error message?); (2) have you tried plotting the profile? (3) singularity shouldn't make the profile impossible, but it would be good to check for (`th <- getME(fitted,"theta"); lwr <- getME(fitted,"lower"); any(th[lwr==0]<1e-7`). (4) Depending on what the profile looks like, you might try setting `delta` to a small value (0.1?) to make the profile stepsize smaller ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker - Thanks very much for your reply. <br/> 

1. No error message, only warnings.   
Yet profile confidence intervals for all beta parameters got values (`-Inf +Inf`) which seems a bit wonky, plus it's something I cannot report.   

2. Yes, see **UPDATE** above. They do seem a bit suspicious...  

3. `FALSE`, so singularity shouldn't be at stake.  

4. Tried, see results for `pp2` under **UPDATE** above. Not much different from result from the original profiles computation (`pp`), yet the profile plots look even more weird...  

Any idea what's going on / how I can deal with it? Tnx!

Comment: What is the interpretation of the plot of the profiles (last plot in your question) that you generated? I did one of that plot with my model and I got curves that are mostly like a logistic regression? What does that mean if I can ask?